# Keyboard shortcut to autocomplete the user in comments

Tags: support, comments, keyboard-shortcuts, autocomplete

While commenting on posts, when we start typing `@` and a few characters that match one of the earlier commentators, a suggestion appears above the comment text area. Is there a shortcut to accept that suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Just press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

Comment: @Dennis Tab doesn't auto-complete particularly when there are multiple choices. See my comments on my answer (though AllDani removed his comments demanding I update my answer to match yours).

Answer (score 13):

Yes, the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key will cycle through potential targets. You can hit <kbd>Space</kbd> to accept. When there are multiple possible targets, you can <kbd>Tab</kbd> until the right one has been highlighted in bold:

> [image]